# Dynamic interface using TableRows

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, android-tablelayout

I am developing an app that creates a dynamic interface according to a string set by the user.

The only thing I've got in my XML file, is a `ScrollView`, the rest is in java code:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sv);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
TableRow[] tr = null;
```

Then I decipher a string, which will tell me how many buttons I need to add. Next to each `Button` should be a `TextView`. In a for-loop, I create the `Buttons` and the `TextViews` and add them to the `TableRow`, which I add to the `TableLayout`, which I add to the `LinearLayout` which I add to the `ScrollView`.

My problem is: I want the `Buttons` to be, say 200dp wide, followed by the `TextView`, but currently it takes the width from `WRAP_CONTENT`. Setting the size of the `Button` with `RelativeLayout` and `setLayoutParams`, does not work when I add it to the `TableRow`.

```
final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                int pixels = (int) (200 * scale + 0.5f);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rel_btn.height = pixels;
                rel_btn.width = pixels;
btn.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);

tr[i].addView(btn);
tr[i].addView(tv);
tl.addView(tr[i]);
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix my problem with the `TableLayout`?

I've read that nested `LinearLayouts` might be a different approach, but I cant seem to find any java examples, only XML - and I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: ScrollView + LinearLayout + Table = ListView. You can do anything with ListView.

Comment: ListView does seem like an alternative. Not a big fan of the looks though. But i cant seem to figure out how to add a button (or textview for that matter) into the listview, with java code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` when your `Button` and `TextView` are the children of a `TableRow`? It should be like this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams rel_btn = new TableRow.LayoutParams(pixels, pixels);
btn.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
```

Also, do you really need the `LinearLayout` that wraps the `TableLayout`? If you're not using that `LinearLayout` for something else you should remove it to improve the views hierarchy.

Comment: First of all, the layoutparams: If i use your code with a dip-size, it says it doesnt support the floats. So i set it with setWidth(pixels) instead as a last resort. Im kind of in a hurry.

LinearLayout: After the TableLayout i got a button, so i do need it. Though, the one time i made a tablelayout not inside a linearlayout, the rows ended up on top of each other, instead of under each other.

Comment: @user1285334 All `LayoutParams` use `int` not `float` values. You can't use directly `dp` you have to calculate them like you already did in your code. So where is the problem?